# Custom import finder only work for namespace with a `__path__` attribute

Tags: python, python-import

I got a remote namespace agency `remote_names`. And I can access remote modules after`import remote_names`then by`remote_names.module_name`. This works fine until one uses the following statements:

```
import remote_names.name  # ImportError: No module named name
from remote_names.name import sub_module  # ImportError: No module named name
```

And I can fix this by defining a custom finder and add it to `sys.meta_path`.

```
class RemoteImporter(object):
    def __init__(self, modules, namespace):
        self.modules = modules
        self.namespace = namespace

        self.modules.__path__ = self.namespaces  # Mark----------------1

    def find_module(self, fullname, path=None):
        if fullname.partition('.')[0] == self.namespace:
            # If import module in namespace, use self as module loader.
            return self
        return None

    def load_module(self, fullname):
        name = fullname.partition('.')[2]
        if len(name) == 0:  # the namespace itself
            return self.modules
        else:
            module = self.modules[name]         
            sys.modules[fullname] = module
            return module
```

But if I didn't set the `__path__` of this agency (as to make it a package). This finder is never get called when I execute import statement. The document doesn't show this:

> **Quote**
>
> If the module is not found in the cache, then sys.meta_path is
>   searched (the specification for sys.meta_path can be found in PEP
>   302). The object is a list of finder objects which are queried in
>   order as to whether they know how to load the module by calling their
>   find_module() method with the name of the module. If the module
>   happens to be contained within a package (as denoted by the existence
>   of a dot in the name), then a second argument to find_module() is
>   given as the value of the **path** attribute from the parent package
>   (everything up to the last dot in the name of the module being
>   imported). If a finder can find the module it returns a loader
>   (discussed later) or returns None.

So is there a reason why the finder never get called when the name gets no `__path__` and what other finder python uses to find the name?

Comment: Can you show us the code you import the non-existing modules? And the whole error trace back message as well.

Comment: @m170897017 Please refer to the first excerpt of code, I've edit the comments to give the exact trace message.